# How to draw using a bitmap context

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I have followed the [sample code on Apple's Quartz programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-TPXREF101) (Listing 2-5) and (after correcting a couple typos in the code like a `calloc` with just one argument that should have been `malloc`) I have this function defined above my `@implementation`:

```
CGContextRef MyCreateBitmapContext (int pixelsWide, int pixelsHigh){

CGContextRef    context = NULL;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
void *          bitmapData;
int             bitmapByteCount;
int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);// 1
bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );// 3
if (bitmapData == NULL)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
    return NULL;
}
context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,// 4
                                 pixelsWide,
                                 pixelsHigh,
                                 8,      // bits per component
                                 bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                 colorSpace,
                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
if (context== NULL)
{
    free (bitmapData);// 5
    fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
    return NULL;
}
CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );// 6

return context;// 7
 }
```

Then I have a method as follows:

```
-(void)testDrawCG{

CGRect myBoundingBox;// 1

CGContextRef myBitmapContext;
CGImageRef myImage;



myBoundingBox = CGRectMake (100, 100, 100, 100);// 2
myBitmapContext = MyCreateBitmapContext (400, 300);// 3
// ********** Your drawing code here ********** // 4
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myBitmapContext, 1, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextFillRect (myBitmapContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 200, 100 ));
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myBitmapContext, 0, 0, 1, .5);
CGContextFillRect (myBitmapContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 100, 200 ));
myImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (myBitmapContext);// 5
CGContextDrawImage(myBitmapContext, myBoundingBox, myImage);// 6
char *bitmapData = CGBitmapContextGetData(myBitmapContext); // 7
CGContextRelease (myBitmapContext);// 8
if (bitmapData) free(bitmapData); // 9
CGImageRelease(myImage);


 }
```

Everything compiles fine, but nothing appears when I call the method.

My understanding is that unlike `drawInRect` which requires UIView to be in the picture (no pun intended), this bitmap drawing can take place from any type of class, even if you are not using UIKit.

In this example, I simply calling the method from `viewDidLoad` as a test, but I'd think I can call it from anywhere, even an NSObject subclass, and expect to see something; at least, that is what is suggested by Apple's docs. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**: Further reading in the Apple docs led me to try this to create the context, rather than use the custom function previously defined:

```
 //    myBitmapContext = MyCreateBitmapContext (400, 300);// 3
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myBoundingBox.size);
myBitmapContext=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

However, the results are still nothing appearing on the screen. Additionally, I get this in the log even though I am not directly calling `malloc`:

```
 malloc: *** error for object 0x102b1020: pointer being freed was not allocated*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Comment: sorry. this question may be out of the topic but how were you able to use this sample code in objective-c? the method format is not in Objective-c. i'm just starting to learn quartzcore and i'd appreciate it if you can answer my question. thanks.

Comment: @user1681701 Apple's Quartz is a C API, therefore the "format" is C, which Objective-C fully supports.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're confused about what it takes to draw something on-screen.  You need a view of some kind -- either a `UIView` in an iOS app, or an `NSView` in a Cocoa app.

Both kinds of views generally require that you draw into them by implementing the `-drawRect:` method. You cannot (easily) draw into them at other times. (This is a vast overgeneralization, really, but it's close enough.)

Alternatively, save your image to a file, then open the file. (For instance, wrap the `CGImageRef` in a `UIImage`, then use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to create PNG data, then `-[NSData writeToFile:atomically:]` to write it to a file.)

Your code also has a few issues.  `-testDrawCG` is OK until here:

```
    myImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (myBitmapContext);// 5
```

You've taken the contents of the bitmap context -- the two rectangles you drew earlier -- and created a `CGImageRef` from them. Think of this image as a snapshot of the context.

```
    CGContextDrawImage(myBitmapContext, myBoundingBox, myImage);// 6
```

Now you're drawing that image *back into* the same context. I have no idea why you would do this. Just skip it.

```
    char *bitmapData = CGBitmapContextGetData(myBitmapContext); // 7
```

Now you're getting the raw data that backs the bitmap context. You don't need to do this.

```
    CGContextRelease (myBitmapContext);// 8
```

OK, you're done with the context, makes sense.

```
    if (bitmapData) free(bitmapData); // 9
```

Don't do this!  You did not get the data using a method with `Create` or `Copy` in the name, therefore you don't own it and you shouldn't free it.

```
    CGImageRelease(myImage);
```

OK, fine, you're done with the image so you release it. But since you did nothing useful with the image then it's no surprise that you don't see it appearing anywhere.

Comment: i have read that a bitmap drawing does not require a UIView, which is why I am using this approach, because I want to draw regardless of the view technology I am using.

Comment: What exactly are you reading?  Yes, you can draw into a bitmap without using a UIView. That doesn't mean the results will automatically show up on the screen, though -- you still need some code to do that, and the usual way is with a UIView of some kind...

Comment: thanks Kurt; the code I have here is verbatim what is the Quartz 2D programming guide, so I'm guessing that not all of Apple's sample code is worth following too closely.

Comment: The code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-CJBHBFFE)?  You actually changed it slightly -- the original had `CGContextDrawImage(myContext, myBoundingBox, myImage)`, so it was drawing the image into a *different* context. You're right that it still has that bogus `CGBitmapContextGetData` and `free`, though; I will file a bug about that, since it's clearly wrong.

Comment: ...and on second look, it's not actually wrong, just confusing. Their code is allocating the `bitmapData`, so it is up to them to `free` it when done. These days, you can let the CGBitmapContext manage its own data, by passing in NULL as the first argument to `CGBitmapContextCreate` -- it's generally much easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the image (`myImage`) to a context that draws on the screen.  Make a subclass of `UIView` and put your `testDrawCG` code into its `drawRect:` method.  Then, still in `drawRect:`, draw `myImage` to the view's context like this:

```
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.bounds, myImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can draw to a bitmap at any time, but the drawing goes onto the bitmap.  If you want to see what you drew, you'll still need to draw it to a UIView or CALayer, during the regular drawing cycle.

For total control over your drawing, follow rob mayoff's suggestion.  If you just want to see what you're currently drawing, you can turn your `CGImageRef` to a `UIImage`, and display that within a `UIImageView`:

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:myImage];
   [someImageView setImage:image];

<del>However, this just means that the drawing to screen happened with the `UIImageView` `drawRect:` method.</del>  I doubt there is any Apple-approved way to draw to the screen outside `drawRect:`.

Comment: Technically, `UIImageView` doesn't use `drawRect:` at all.  [UIImageView Class Reference: Special Considerations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006889-CH3-DontLinkElementID_3)

Comment: @rob mayoff: Thanks, I hadn't noticed that.